# iOS platform: Running application on background

Tags: iphone, ios4, ios-simulator

am new to the ios application development.
I had developed an application on iOS platform using 4.3 SDK.

When it runs on simulator or a device, if we are trying to press on the application icon again after quit the application at run time, the application is again starts its execution from the begining, not from the previous stage it has stopped.

By going throgh the documentation i came to know the multitasking facility is inbuilt for an iOS application.

Or we need to do any coding for implementing this multitasking facility.? Experts please help.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Basically you should be able to go background and then foreground when using the simulator. remember that when running on simulator the GDB debugger is attached to the process thus you cannot terminate the app and start again but you can go background and start again. I think there is a good chance you are crashing and that's why the app starts again. Try to implement the app delegate methods "didResignActive" and "didBecomeActive" and make sure you manage the saving of the state correctly there...